# priority-web-sdk: uploadImage

Tags: javascript, canvas, erp

I'm trying to upload an image using [uploadImage](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#uploadImage) from the documentation. The first thing I notice is that the method does not seem to be exposed by the package.

There *is* a method with a very similar signature `uploadDataUrl`, which I'm using in the code below, but I can't tell if the usage is identical.

There's a full example of my [test page here](https://erpdemo.emerge-it.co.uk/ui/upload.html).

```
save(curform) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        curform.uploadDataUrl("{0}{1}".f(this.postURL, this.filename), "png").then(uploadResult => {
            if (uploadResult.isLast == 1) {
                // Save the upload result with fieldUpdate.

            } else {
                var er = {};
                er.message = "Don't know what happened...";
                reject(er);
            }

        }).catch(er => { reject(er) })
    })
}
```

The [FileUploadResult](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#FileUploadResult) looks like this:

`JSONObject {jsObject: Object, progress: 100, isLast: false}`

Obviously if the upload was successful there should be `file.Key` and `file.Value` in the [FileUploadResult](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#FileUploadResult).

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the name of the function is `uploadDataUrl` indeed. We will update the documentation. Thank you.

Second thing, the `file` entry is returned upon success. Don't use `Promise` here because in this case the response is returned several times with different progress value each time. Use callbacks instead.